# Show post excerpt

Tags: posts, functions, loop

I want to show several post excerpt, so I create function

```
function my_excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
    } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    }
    $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
    return $excerpt;
}
```

and I use it:

```
<?php  echo bereza_excerpt(35); ?>
```

but I have problem - I cant save post formatting.

Is it possible to recreate this function and save text formatting in post excerpt?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `substr` in your function:

```
function my_excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    if(strlen($excerpt) > $limit) {
        // trim to $limit characters
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $limit);
        // remove any truncated words
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strippos($excerpt, " "));
        $excerpt = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    }
    return $excerpt;
}
```

Another way is to filter the excerpt, which will change the length of all your excerpts sitewide:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');
function my_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 30;
}
```

Comment: what is "strippos" function?